# Swift 4 URLsession with Authentication API Key

Tags: swift, rest, api, authentication, shippo

I am trying to make a `POST` Request for the `Shippo REST API` in Swift, but since it needs an API Authentication key I cannot figure out how to implement the key in the `URLSession` in Swift 4. As the Apple documentation puts it I cannot use `urlsession.shared` method.
The `cURL` command is:

```
curl https://api.goshippo.com/addresses/ \
 -H "Authorization: ShippoToken shippo_test_Token_Here" \
 -d name="Shawn Ippotle" \ -d company="Shippo" \
 -d street1="215 Clayton St." \
 -d street2="" \
 -d city="San Francisco" \
 -d state="CA" \
 -d zip=94117 \
 -d country="US" \
 -d phone="+1 555 341 9393" \
 -d email="shippotle@goshippo.com"\
 -d is_residential=True\
 -d metadata="Customer ID 123456"
```

Comment: I would definitely recommend using Alamofire to do this

Comment: @NevinJethmalani can you show me how to do it in Alamofire?

Comment: Yes of course. I just posted it. If that is helpful, you can accept my answer. It might help others with similar issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here it is using Alamofire. I hope this helps. I have tested it and it works.

```
func mainRequest(){

    var headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "content-type": "application/json"
    ]

    let credentials = "shippo_test_8dc780c66d5dae1c42868596c0b359ba89108df9"
    headers["Authorization"] = "ShippoToken \(credentials)"

    var parameters:Parameters = [String : Any]()

    parameters["name"] = "Shawn Ippotle"
    parameters["company"] = "Shippo"
    parameters["street1"] = "215 Clayton St."
    parameters["street2"] = ""
    parameters["city"] = "San Francisco"
    parameters["state"] = "CA"
    parameters["zip"] = "94117"
    parameters["phone"] = "+1 555 341 9393"
    parameters["country"] = "US"
    parameters["email"] = "shippotle@goshippo.com"
    parameters["is_residential"] = "True"
    parameters["metadata"] = "Customer ID 123456"

    let url = "https://api.goshippo.com/addresses"

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters , encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let swiftyJson = JSON(value)
                print ("return as JSON using swiftyJson is: \(swiftyJson)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print ("error: \(error)")
            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

what about something like:

```
// preparing http request
let yourUrl = URL(string: "https://api.goshippo.com/addresses/")! // whatever is your url
let yourAuthorizationToken = "ShippoToken shippo_test_Token_Here" // whatever is your token
let yourPayload = Data() // whatever is your payload

var request = URLRequest(url:yourUrl)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue(yourAuthorizationToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
request.httpBody = yourPayload

// executing the call
let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    // your stuff here
})
task.resume()
```